# React differently if second time user visits domain

Tags: dns, persistent, audit-trail, krl

I am working on building a Kynetx app that fires a different action on a domain if it is the second time a user has visited the page. I think I need to use a persistant trail to mark when a user visits a page but I'm not sure how to check the trail to see if a value is already there and matches the current domain.

Current code:

```
rule put_data_onto_trail {
  select when pageview ".*"
  pre {
    domain = page:url("domain");
  }
  {
    notify("Thanks for visiting #{domain}","You visit has been recorded") with sticky = true;
  }
  fired {
    mark ent:visitedDomains with domain;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KRL provides [the `seen` operator](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Trails) just for this purpose. It takes a regular expression as a string. So your `if` check could look something like this:

```
if seen ".*awesome.*" in ent:mytrail then {
    // take over the world
}
```

Comment: `".*awesome.*"` could be simplified to `"awesome"` to make it a little more clear.